# Get Value of XML

Tags: php, xml

I have been testing a lot of XML parser function but I had no success extracting the value.
I wonder what went wrong.
I want to get the value of STATUS_DESC AND STATUS_CODE in XML.

XML doc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<string xmlns="http://service.xxx/">
<ErrorInfo>
<STATUS_CODE>0105</STATUS_CODE>
<REQUEST_TIME>11/28/2014 3:54:06 AM</REQUEST_TIME>
<TIME_INTERVAL>300</TIME_INTERVAL>
<STATUS_DESC>Unable to fetch Data </STATUS_DESC>
</ErrorInfo>
</string>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml);

var_dump($xml); 
// var_dump result:
//    object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (1) { [0]=> string(48) "010511/28/2014 3:54:06 AM300Unable to fetch Data" } 
$error=$xml->ErrorInfo; 
$error1=$xml->ErrorInfo->STATUS_DESC;
echo $error; // Nothing
echo $error1; // Nothing

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already on the parent node so your can access its children directly:

```
echo $xml->STATUS_CODE;
```

As seen [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KBqb2n)

With your revision:

```
$error_status_desc = (string) $xml->ErrorInfo->STATUS_DESC;
echo $error_status_desc;
```

[Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bKxfi9)

Comment: I am sorry. I tried your method but it is not working too. I missed the XML detail. I have updated the XML. please look at it

Comment: @xyonme your xml changed, i revised something

Comment: strangely in my app , the XMl was there  and it didn't work. var_dump() the error_status_desc => string(0) ""

Comment: @xyonme well, since these are the only codes you provided, this is the only one i could work on. it seems fine on this end. where did you get this xml anyway?

Comment: Yes. I see your example works well. I got it from a CURL response.

Comment: @xyonme it seems its inside a namespaced node, could you post the exact xml here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65794/discussion-between-xyonme-and-ghost).